# Trouble voting up - broken site - where's the web admin email?

Tags: support, voting

On garden.stackexchange, I have trouble voting up answer posts to my own questions.  I click the up arrow, it says you need to login or register, I click login, I click by-stackexchange id, it brings me back to the page, I click the up arrow, and repeat.  It never logged me in properly.  Somethings wrong!  Firefox 12.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with your account on Gardening which was preventing voting.  This has been fixed.

I apologize for the trouble.